# delete children without update them before @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, constraints, persistence, one-to-many

I have a problem with hybernate
I have 2 classes like that :

```
public Class Race {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="race", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Lap> laps = new ArrayList<>(0);
    ...
}

public Class Lap {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
   @JoinColumn(name = "RACE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Race race;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "nextLap", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Lap previousLap;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   @JoinColumn(name = "NEXT_ID")
   private Lap nextLap;
 ...
}
```

In my database I also have a unique constraint with NEXT_ID and RACE_ID
My problem is when I want to delete my Race, with

```
txn = session.getTransaction();
txn.begin();
race = session.merge(race);
session.remove(race);
session.flush(); //=>Exception here
txn.commit();
```

I get the result:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
> execute batch     at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1364)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1347)
> at
> package.DAORace.deleteRace(DAORace.java:122)

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint
> (LAP_UK1) violated

Hibernate do an update on my lap when I delete the race and my contraint is violated.
My question is how to delete children properly, without update, when I delete parent ?

Note : If I have only one child, I can delete it without any exception, if I have 2 or more children, I have an exception.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

For removing entities as a cascade, the best approach is removing them with a few queries.

For example:

```
em.createQuery("delete from Lap p where p.race.id = :id).setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();

em.createQuery("delete from Race r where r.id = :id).setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
```

https://thorben-janssen.com/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/ read here for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that It will work but in fact I have a lot of object under my Lap object to delete to as a cascade (but without unique constraint)
Writing queries will be a little bit tedious and dangerous if I forgot an entity to delete
I think that hibernate could do it correctly